# Want to display data on webpage when I select value from select box in php

Tags: php, html, sql

This is my entire page code. my page name is manage-video2.php
In this code how can i display the record from database through select statement in my webpage. please any one can help me to find out the bug in this code and fix that bug. i rally great full to you.

```
<?php
   include('config.php');
   session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
<script>
$("#sel1").change(function(){
$.get("manage-video2.php?value="+$(this).val(),     function(data, status){
$("#resultdiv").html(data);
   });
 });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container pad20">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12">
               <div class="panel panel-primary">
                    <div class="panel-heading">Manage Videos
 <div class="form-group">
 <label for="sel1">Select list:</label>
 <select class="form-control" id="sel1" name="sel1" data-style="btn-primary">
    <option value="1">25 Records</option>
    <option value="2">50 Records</option>
    <option value="3">75 Records</option>
    <option value="4">More than 100</option>
 </select>
             </div>
        </div>                  
          <div id="resultdiv">
          <form method="POST" action="processor.php">

         <table id="table1" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
             <thead>
              <tr><th>Video Name</th></tr>
             </thead>
             <?php
                 $access = $_SESSION['login'];
                 if($access == "white"){
                   if(isset($_GET['value'])){
                     $sql = "SELECT * FROM videos ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ".$_GET['value'];
                   else{ 
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM videos ORDER BY id DESC";}
                    $query = $conn->query($sql);
                    $i=1;
                    while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                    $video_name = $row['video_name'];
                    echo "
                    <tbody>
                      <tr><td id='test10' class='text-center'><b>$video_name</b></td></tr>
                      </tbody>";
                       } $i++;
                    }
                    else {
                       header ("location:index.php");
                         }
                    ?>
            </table>
            <!-- End data table --> 
       </form>  
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
 </div><!-- /.container -->
  <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: add a `LIMIT` clause

Comment: but how to establish a link between options and sql query? as i select and data display. please with example. @Ghost

Comment: have you tried forms before?, i'd assume you already have. just treat your select box as you normally would, use the user input and add it in your query statement accordingly.

Comment: i have already data in database. now want to fetch data and display on webpage.

Comment: are you using ajax or form submitting (realod page) method

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the **LIMIT** in the sql query .

**First of all , add a name for your `select` and add method `POST` :

```
<select class="form-control" id="sel1" name="select11" method="POST" data-style="btn-primary">
```

**Now you need to put the value of the option into a variable in php:**

```
$select_value=$_POST['select11'];
```

**And then make a variable in which you store the LIMIT of data to be printed :**

```
    switch ($select_value) {
        case "1" :
           $limit="25";

            break;
        case "2":
 $limit="50";



            break;
        case "3":
 $limit="75";
            break;

          }
```

**Last step :**

```
 if($select_value=="4")
    {
         $sql = "SELECT * FROM videos ORDER BY id DESC";
    }
    else
    {
         $sql = "SELECT * FROM videos ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ".$limit;
    }

                     $query = $conn->query($sql);
                     $i=1;
                     while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                         $video_name = $row['video_name'];
                         echo "
                           <tbody>
                           <tr><td id='test10' class='text-center'><b>$video_name</b></td></tr>
                           </tbody>";
                           }
```

**So your code will be looking like this :**

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="sel1">Select list:</label>
   <select class="form-control" id="sel1" name="select11" data-style="btn-primary">
       <option value="1">25 Records</option>
       <option value="2">50 Records</option>
       <option value="3">75 Records</option>
       <option value="4">More than 100</option>
   </select>
</div> 


<form method="POST" action="processor.php">
     <!-- start data table -->
     <table id="table1" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
       <thead>
         <tr><th>Video Name</th></tr>
       </thead>
       <?php
           $access = $_SESSION['login'];
$select_value=$_POST['select11'];
  switch ($select_value) {
        case "1" :
           $limit="25";

            break;
        case "2":
 $limit="50";
            break;
        case "3":
 $limit="75";
            break;

          }
              if($access == "white"){
     if($select_value=="4")
        {
             $sql = "SELECT * FROM videos ORDER BY id DESC";
        }
        else
        {
             $sql = "SELECT * FROM videos ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ".$limit;
        }

                 $query = $conn->query($sql);
                 $i=1;
                 while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                     $video_name = $row['video_name'];
                     echo "
                       <tbody>
                       <tr><td id='test10' class='text-center'><b>$video_name</b></td></tr>
                       </tbody>";
                       } $i++;
                }
           else {
                header ("location:index.php");
                }
         ?>
     </table>
 </form>
```

Edit 
-Added method in the form , look in the top.

### -Add Ajax data post in the `<head>` of your html page where your form is.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">


function getInfo(){
    var xmlhttp;
    var select1= document.getElementById("sel1").value;


    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    else
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xmlhttp.readyState==1)
        document.getElementById("resultdiv").innerHTML = "<span style= 'color:blue;'>Connecting to the server ... </span>";
    else if (xmlhttp.readyState==2)
        document.getElementById("resultdiv").innerHTML = "<span style= 'color:blue;'>Request sent successfully ...</span>";
    else if (xmlhttp.readyState==3)
        document.getElementById("resultdiv").innerHTML = "<span style= 'color:blue;'>Analyzing request ... </span>";

    if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 & xmlhttp.status == 200)
        document.getElementById("resultdiv").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;

}

xmlhttp.open("POST","**youraction_page.php**",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("select11="+select1);
    }

         </script>
```

Then add a submit button (As i'm not so good with jQuery events so this is the best way i can sugget )  , or just a button

```
<input type="button" name="submit" value="Go !" OnClick="GetInfo()" />
```

Comment: bro this code is not running. which you given me. now i edit my question and post all code of my page. can you please edit this? great full to you. @user3779014

Comment: Bro , i can't get the script written in Javascript so clearly .
I can help you with PHP part , and maybe submitting with a normal Ajax.

Comment: this script will work your code? are this will work mine code that i put in question. and one thing more. where to put button?

Comment: Replace everything in your two pages with the ones i did posted of course with adding the edits in two separated files , the first contains the form , in which you need to put the Submit button after `select`  , the second one will contain the php code and will be named `youraction_page.php` . 
This way everything should work good.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use ajax for that.

```
$("#sel1").change(function(){
 $.get("result.php?value="+$(this).val(),     function(data, status){
      $("#resultdiv").html(data);
  });
});
```

In the php file, change your query to:

```
 if(isset($_GET['value'])){

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM videos ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ".$_GET['value'];}
  else{ 

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM videos ORDER BY id DESC";}
```

Note: Use prepared statements with MySQLi or PDO. Sanitize user input. And don't use `SELECT *` in sql queries. Always specify the columns you want output from.

Comment: Bro is this sql statement is true. because it gives an error. @CoderDude

Comment: If you run it singly directly without the get parameter, this will obviously give you an error.

Comment: so how to run it? how to put parameter. please help me.

Comment: Just add a div to your html page with id resultdiv. Include jquery. And run the html page.

Comment: this is the name of page which contain all this code.

Comment: Is it the same page? Keep `manage-video2.php` as a separate page with only the sql query running.

Comment: it is the same page. all the code is run on the same page. the page name is manage-video2.php and above all the code is in this page.

Comment: Keep it as a separate page